# perfect lens: expression for interface

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, closed-form, applications

Suppose I want to find a function $(x,z) \mapsto y((x^2+z^2)^{1/2})$ which must represent the interface between two translucent media with different refractive index and which must yield a perfect lens, i.e. a lens without [spherical abberation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_aberration): light rays coming in from $y=-\infty$ and propagating parallel with the $y$-axis must be refracted at the interface in accordance with [Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law) and the outgoing light ray must hit the $y$-axis in a certain point $F=(0,c,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with the "focus" $F$ independent of whichever incoming light ray we considered (this latter property is what makes the lens "perfect"). Suppose we agree to choose WLOG that $y(0)=0$. After some elementary geometry, I find that the problem reduces to the ODE
$$\frac{x}{(x^2+[c-y(x)]^2)^{1/2}} = \sin(\alpha(x))\cos(\theta(x)) - \sin(\theta(x))\cos(\alpha(x))\\
\sin(\alpha(x)) = \frac{y'(x)}{(1+[y'(x)]^2)^{1/2}}=n\sin(\theta(x)) \qquad(1)$$
with $n>1$ the refractive index of the medium above the interface relative to the medium below. I believe giants such as Leibniz, Newton, Huygens must have arrived at this point and gotten stuck in finding a closed-form solution to this ODE. Browsing the web I found [a paper claiming a closed-form solution](https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/abstract.cfm?uri=ao-57-31-9341) (at least to a similar problem) and reading the contents of their article they claim the solution involves a simple expression without reverting to the use of [non-elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). I'm skeptical though, so therefore the following question:

**Q: Can solutions of the ODE (1), subject to the initial condition $y(0)=0$, be expressed in terms of elementary functions? What is the most transparent account of the solutions to this ODE?**

(the 2nd question can be understood in the same vein as how the [Kepler problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_problem) may be difficult to solve with e.g. time as the independent variable, but if one promotes a related variable -namely the angle- as the independent variable a closed-form solution in terms of elementary functions is easily obtained.)

(Apparently the problem of designing abberation-free lenses is colloquially known as the "Wasserman-Wolf problem")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem ought to be solved with a closed-form expression. See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.1059.pdf) for details.